# Exit command execution after being asked for input

Tags: git, shell, ubuntu, unix, terminal

Im writing a simple script using,

```
git-ls-remote
```

I want to fetch sha1 of last commit of given by user repo, the problem is that if repo doesn't exist git asks me for username and password, is there any way to abort command when asked for user input?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Providing code snippets helps us troubleshoot.

`--exit-code` seems to be what you are looking for, pulled directly from the [`git-ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html) documentation.

> --exit-code
>
> Exit with status "2" when no matching refs are found in the remote repository. >Usually the command exits with status "0" to indicate it successfully talked with the >remote repository, whether it found any matching refs.